# How to properly implement facebook login for GWT facebook app?

Tags: facebook, gwt, facebook-oauth

I am creating an app on Facebook and am trying to figure out what the proper way to authenticate and log into the app is. I don't want it to be accessible when they log out of Facebook and currently using OAuth 2.0 the app still totally functions by going to apps.facebook.com/myappname, even though the top bar to log into Facebook is there.

Here is my `onModuleLoad` :

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
  AuthRequest req = new AuthRequest(FACEBOOK_AUTH_URL, FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID);
  AUTH.login(req, new Callback<String, Throwable>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String token) {
      f_token = token;
      startAppAfterLogin();
    }

    @Override public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
      Window.Location.assign("https://www.facebook.com/login.php");
    }
  });
}
```

Obviously the `startAppAfterLogin()` is still being called when they have logged out, anyone have any ideas what to do?

Comment: You will need to specify some auth scopes on the `AuthRequest` or else Facebook will not know what information you're asking for. See the example here: https://code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/source/browse/trunk/samples/multi/com/google/api/gwt/oauth2/samples/multi/client/OAuth2SampleEntryPoint.java#190

Comment: Also, if you request multiple scopes, you will need to set the scope delimiter to "," since Facebook expects scopes to be separated by commas and not spaces (as is in the spec).

Comment: That doesn't fix anything. The issue is that I want it to only be accessible while they are logged into Facebook like most apps do. Mine they can still go to the URL after logging out and everything functions which it shouldn't.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any way to query the Facebook API for a user's logged-in state. Logged-in state is also not part of the OAuth 2.0 standard, it is intended to work even while the user is offline or not at the computer.

Comment: Would it make sense to add some Javascript that checks their log in status then?